# Angular 4 - Book marked pages fail to load CSS

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-router

I'm new to Angular, but managed to create a static website, http://beta.catatumbo.io. This site is accessible over the Internet. Everything works nicely when using the provided navigation. However, running into an issue with bookmarked URLs. First level bookmarks (e.g. http://beta.catatumbo.io/overview) works fine. Second level (e.g. http://beta.catatumbo.io/documentation/quick-start) fails to render properly because of a failure to load the styles bundle. Console in Chrome shows the below error:

```
quick-start:1 GET http://beta.catatumbo.io/documentation/styles.ccd5e2c92917dc0c0a9c.bundle.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Not sure why the request is looking for the styles bundle in `documentation` folder instead of `root (/)`.

Below is relevant code:

**angular-cli.json**

Styles array is setup to load the below CSS files.

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/prismjs/themes/prism.css"
  ],
```

**routes.ts**

Below are the route definitions:

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: {title: 'Catatumbo - JPA like Persistence Framework for Google Cloud Datastore'}},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: {title: 'Catatumbo - JPA like Persistence Framework for Google Cloud Datastore'}},
  {path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent, data: {title: 'Overview & Features | Catatumbo'}},
  {path: 'documentation', component: DocumentationComponent, data: {title: 'Documentation | Catatumbo'}},
  {path: 'documentation/quick-start', component: QuickStartComponent, data: {title: 'Quick Start | Catatumbo'}},
  {path: 'documentation/video-tutorials', component: VideoTutorialsComponent, data: {title: 'Video Tutorials | Catatumbo'}},
  {path: 'documentation/api-documentation', component: ApiDocumentaionComponent, data: {title: 'API Documentation | Catatumbo'}},
  {path: 'documentation/release-notes', component: ReleaseNotesComponent, data: {title: 'Release Notes | Catatumbo'}},
  {path: 'source-code', component: SourceCodeComponent, data: {title: 'Source Code | Catatumbo'}},
  {path: 'support', component: SupportComponent, data: {title: 'Support | Catatumbo'}},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, data: {title: 'About the Author | Catatumbo'}},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];
```

All the above components are defined directly under the src/app folder.

All bookmarks (first & second level) work fine when running in dev mode (`ng serve`), but the mentioned issue happens in prod mode (`ng serve --prod`). So seems like something wrong with the packaging or I must not be doing it right. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Catatumbo.Io</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16 32x32 64x64" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="./assets/favicon-192.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="160x160" href="./assets/favicon-160.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="./assets/favicon-96.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="64x64" href="./assets/favicon-64.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/favicon-32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./assets/favicon-16.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./assets/favicon-57.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="./assets/favicon-114.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="./assets/favicon-72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="./assets/favicon-144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="./assets/favicon-60.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="./assets/favicon-120.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="./assets/favicon-76.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="./assets/favicon-152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./assets/favicon-180.png">
<body>
<!-- Begin Google Analytics -->
<script>
  (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
      (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
      m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
  })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-21739301-2', 'auto');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->

<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem for you :) Move the css link below the meta tag like this. Base href should be set above all your links in the header. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c22C3.png)

Comment: I've updated the original post to include the code for `index.html`. I don't refer to any of the CSS, other than in `angular-cli.json`. I have the `<base>` tag at the top of `<head>` element.  The style bundle is included by the package mechanism (webpack?). So, I don't have control over it. Again, it works fine in `dev` mode, but breaks in `prod` mode.

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes.ts` add `children` routes like this and try

```
{
path: 'documentation', 
component: DocumentationComponent, 
data: {title: 'Documentation | Catatumbo'},
children:[
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'quick-start',
      pathMatch:'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'quick-start', 
        component: QuickStartComponent, 
        data: {title: 'Quick Start | Catatumbo'}
    },
    {
        path: 'video-tutorials', 
        component: VideoTutorialsComponent, 
        data: {title: 'Video Tutorials | Catatumbo'}
    },
    {
        path: 'api-documentation', 
        component: ApiDocumentaionComponent, 
        data: {title: 'API Documentation | Catatumbo'}
    }
]
},
```

remove the `redirectTo: 'quick-start'` if dont want to redirect `/documentation` to `documentation/quick-start` when the `/documentation` hitted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turns out that my `index.html` is missing `</head>` tag. For this reason, the generated DOM ends up with two `<head>` tags, one that imports the styles bundle, but it does not have `<base>`. Everything is working fine after I fixed the `index.html` to close the `<head>` tag.